# pysnmp OID resolution

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

Using pysnmp, how you perform resolution on queries that return an OID instead of value?

I wrote a lookup tool using pysnmp, here are the inputs and results :

```
./run_snmp_discovery.py --host 1.1.1.1 --community XXXXXX --command get --mib_oid_index  '{ "mib" : "SNMPv2-MIB", "oid" : "sysObjectID", "index" : "0"  }' --verbose
Debug: 'varBind': SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.1.222
{"0": {"sysObjectID": "SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.1.222"}}
```

How can the result be converted to the text value `cisco7206VXR` (reference http://www.circitor.fr/Mibs/Html/C/CISCO-PRODUCTS-MIB.php#cisco7206VXR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using code [like this](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/quick-start.html#fetch-snmp-variable):

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
           CommunityData('public'),
           UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
           ContextData(),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0)))
)

for varBind in varBinds:
    print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

And you want MIB object to be represented as an OID, then the `varBind` in the code above is actually an [ObjectType](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.ObjectType) class instance which behaves like a tuple of two elements. The first element is [ObjectIdentity](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.ObjectIdentity) which has the [.getOid](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.ObjectIdentity.getOid) method:

```
>>> objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0)
>>> objectIdentity.resolveWithMib(mibViewController)
>>> objectIdentity.getOid()
ObjectName('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0')
```

If you want MIB object and its value to be fully represented in MIB terms (i.e. value resolved into an enumeration), then you just need to load the MIB that defines that MIB object (perhaps, CISCO-PRODUCTS-MIB) using [.loadMibs()](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.ObjectIdentity.loadMibs) method. You might also need to set up a [search path](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.ObjectIdentity.addAsn1MibSource) to let pysnmp find the MIB you refer.

Comment: this worked. I marked your response as having answered the question. thanks for the quick response! a little more information -- we won't know in advance the device that is being enumerated -- using this approach, I believe it will necessary to load all researched MIBS using the loadMibs() method.